# Solving and plotting derivative included function

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Please suggest a method that I can use to solve (for y(x) and y'(x)) and plot the derivative related given function.

Note: `L` may be vary):

```
a = 2.7*10^-3; θ = Pi/6; g = 9.8; ρ = 1000; σ = 70*10^-3;
L = 4*10^-3;
δp = 2*σ/L - g*(ρ*L)/2; 
y' = D[y, x];
1 + y'/Sqrt[(1 + y'^2)] ==  x^2/(2*a^2) + (δp*x)/σ + (1 - Cos[θ]
```

Comment: Please clarify what the function is, and what variable the derivative is taken with respect to.

Comment: I suppose OP needs to solve differential equation on `y[x]` with parameter `L` and some initial condition, this can be done like: `δp[L_]:=2*σ/L - g*(ρ*L)/2; sol = ParametricNDSolve[{1 + y'[x]/Sqrt[(1 + y'[x]^2)] == x^2/(2*a^2) + (δp[L]*x)/σ + (1 + Cos[θ]),  y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, {L}]`. Then he can plot `y'`: `Plot[y'[0.004][x] /. sol, {x, 
  Sequence @@ First[(y[0.004] /. sol)["Domain"]]}]`, I substituted in here value of `L` given in question.

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to solve for and plot the derivative `y'[x], or do you want to solve for and plot the function `y[x]`?

Comment: Also note that equations are expressed with `==`, not `=` which is an assignment. So you likely want `1 + y'[x]/Sqrt[(1 + y'[x]^2)] ==  x^2/(2*a^2) + (δp*x)/σ + (1 + Cos[θ])`

Comment: @Alx. That looks more like an answer than a comment. I suggest you write it up as answer.

Comment: @m_goldberg, Thnks for the suggestion. I updated the question.

Comment: Hi Gopal. I noticed you haven't accepted any answers to [your 14 questions over the last 3 years](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/43205/gopal-verma?tab=questions). May I suggest you revisit  those q/as and consider accepting answers that you think best answer your questions.

Comment: @Kglr, I given an up-vote and also write thanks that (answer) code is working. Is there any key to click for accepting the answers?

Comment: Gopal, you can click [checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/) to accept an answer.

Answer (score 8):

OK, write my comment as answer. If I understood OP's intention correctly, he wants to solve for `y[x]` and plot `y'[x]`. The equation contains a parameter `L`, so we need to use `ParametricNDSolve`:

```
a = 2.7*10^-3; θ = Pi/6; g = 9.8; ρ = 1000; σ = 70*10^-3;
δp[L_] := 2*σ/L - g*(ρ*L)/2;

sol = ParametricNDSolve[{1 + y'[x]/Sqrt[(1 + y'[x]^2)] == 
    x^2/(2*a^2) + (δp[L]*x)/σ + (1 + Cos[θ]), 
   y[0] == 0}, y, {x, 0, 1}, {L}]
```

Now the solution can be plotted for some value of `L` (I used here initial value from the question):

```
Plot[y'[0.004][x] /. sol, {x, Sequence @@ First[(y[0.004] /. sol)["Domain"]]},
 AxesLabel -> {x, y'[x]}]
```

[image]

To vary `L` one can use `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot[y'[L][x] /. sol, {x, 
   Sequence @@ First[(y[L] /. sol)["Domain"]]}, 
  AxesLabel -> {x, y'[x]},
  PlotLabel -> Row[{Style["L", Italic], "\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]", L}]], 
 {{L, 0.004}, 0.002, 0.02, 0.002}]
```

Another possibility is using table-like representation:

```
Grid@Partition[
 Plot[y'[#][x] /. sol, {x, 
  Sequence @@ First[(y[#] /. sol)["Domain"]]}, 
 AxesLabel -> {x, y'[x]}, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{L, "\[ThinSpace]=\[ThinSpace]", #}]] & /@ 
 Range[0.002, 0.02, 0.002], 2]
```

**EDIT**

To answer edited question. First we can plot `y[L][x]` as function of `x`, then one approach is to take points from this plot and interchange coordinates, as a result we can plot `x` as a function of `y[L][x]`. This can be done in the following way:

```
With[{L = 0.004}, With[{plot = Plot[Evaluate[y[L][x] /. sol], 
{x, Sequence @@ First[(y[L] /. sol)["Domain"]]}, PlotRange -> All]}, 
   ListLinePlot[First[Cases[plot, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]] /. {x_, y_} :> {y, x}, 
PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {HoldForm[y[x]], HoldForm[x]}, 
    GridLines -> {None, {L}}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Gray], 
PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {Automatic, Scaled[0.1]}}, 
    Epilog -> Text["L level", {y[L][L/10] /. sol, L}, {0, 1.1}]]]]
```

[image]

One can also use `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[With[{plot = Plot[Evaluate[y[L][x] /. sol], 
{x, Sequence @@ First[(y[L] /. sol)["Domain"]]}, PlotRange -> All]}, 
ListLinePlot[First[Cases[plot, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity]] /. {x_, y_} :> {y, x}, 
PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {HoldForm[y[x]], HoldForm[x]}, 
GridLines -> {None, {L}}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Thick, Gray], 
PlotRangePadding -> {Automatic, {Automatic, Scaled[0.1]}}, 
Epilog -> Text["L level", {y[L][L/10] /. sol, L}, {0, 1.1}]]], 
{{L, 0.004}, 0.002, 0.02, 0.002, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

With parameters given this (both `Manipulate` and `ListLinePlot`) only works up to `L = 0.006`, then the shape of the plot is changed, and one has to comment out `Epilog` part to plot for greater values of `L`.

Comment: Thanks, It is working.

Comment: Please also suggest how to vary L (e.g. {L,.001,0.02,.0002(step)})

Comment: See my edit about how to vary `L`.

Comment: Please look at the update, I added the expected plot. Please suggest how to get it. ( you can put (1-cos(\theta)) instead of (1+cos(\theta))

Comment: Thanks for your update, but the shape of a graph not matching, especially the upper half part.